# Trying to find unique XPath of button

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have a case where XPath is not unique and matches 3 elements on the page whose elementary position changes with refresh:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12   Hover">
    <button data-testid="continueCheckoutButton" ng- 
    class="continueDellMetricsClass" ng-click="continueButtonClick()" ng- 
    disabled="disableContinueButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block 
    continueButton" data-metrics="" type="button">Checkout</button>
```

Please help me finding the unique XPath or CSS path of this button element.

The other two HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <button data-testid="continueCheckoutButton" ng- 
    class="continueDellMetricsClass" ng-click="continueButtonClick()" ng- 
    disabled="disableContinueButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block 
    continueButton" data-metrics="" type="button" style="background: 
    rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;">Checkout</button>

     <div>
                <button ng-class="continueDellMetricsClass" ng- 
      click="continueButtonClick()" ng-disabled="disableContinueButton" 
      class="btn btn-success btn-block continueButton" data- 
      testid="continueCheckoutButton" data-metrics="" type="button" 
      style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid 
       red;">Checkout</button>
            </div>
```

This is what results in 3 elements match:

```
   //button[@data-testid = 'continueCheckoutButton']
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you share HTML for all 3 buttons?

Comment: yes html of all 3 buttons are required before giving the answers.

Comment: @user3121891 As the HTML contains multiple `<button>` tags with similar attributes so to locate a particular `<button>` tag you have update the question with the relevant HTML from which we can differentiate the desired element from the others and help you to derive a _Locator Strategy_ which will identify your desired element.

Comment: I just updated description, please have a ook. thanks for your time bro

Comment: @user3121891, check my answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To distinguish target button from two other you can try:

```
//button[not(@style) and .="Checkout"]
```

P.S. If HTML for all nodes seem to be identical, you can use index of required one:

```
(//button[not(@style) and .="Checkout"])[1]
```

Note that in XPath indexation starts from `1`, so index for the first node will be `[1]`.

You can also use `find_elements...()` instead of `find_element...()` to get a list of elements and select required with `[index]`.

Comment: i think i would go with indexing and as there are three elements match, in my case my concern is addressed with (//button[. = 'Checkout'])[3]. I will accept this answer. Thanks Andersson!

Answer (score 0):

To click on the button with text as **Checkout** you have to induce wait through *WebDriverWait* and you can use either of the following code block (Python) :

- `CSS_SELECTOR` :

  ```
  button.btn.btn-success.btn-block.continueButton[ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass'][data-testid='continueCheckoutButton']
  ```
- `XPATH` :

  ```
  //button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block continueButton' and contains(.,'Checkout')]
  ```

**Note** : As the element is a *Angular* element you have to induce proper *WebDriverWait* through your respective *Selenium Language Binding Art*.

---

### Update

As per your updated *HTML* you can use the following *Locator Strategy* :

- `XPATH` :

  ```
  //button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block continueButton' and contains(.,'Checkout') and not (@style='background')]
  ```

Comment: Thanks Debanjan for your reply. I tried this xpath but again this is resuting in two elements. one is on page and other is hidden but the xpath checker shows two results. :(

Comment: Try the updated answer with CSS and update me the status.

Comment: Without knowing of all 3 buttons address, you can't write a unique locator.

Comment: @user3121891 Check out my answer update and let me know the status

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@class='col-xs-12']/button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block continueButton' and contains(.,'Checkout')]
```

Try this.

Comment: @user3121891 add your comments if not working for you